# Get highest values from database-table

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, logic, concept

I have this structure in my database-table:

[image]

Now I need most clicked usernames(Top 4), like this output:

> 1. name10: 15
> 2. name10: 14
> 3. name10: 13
> 4. name10: 12

I just have this at the moment:

```
    $result = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM table");
    $result->execute();
    while ($user = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        // save data in array´s ? 
    }
```

Do I have to create multidimensional arrays?

Comment: `SELECT username,clicks FROM table ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 4`

Answer (score 1):

To get only the highest number, you can use `MAX`:

```
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT MAX(clicks) AS clicks FROM table");
```

To get the top 4 results and order by clicks, you use `ORDER BY`:

```
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 4");
$result->execute();
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $key => $array) {
    echo $key + 1 . '. ' . $array['username'] . ': ' . $array['clicks'] . '<br/><br/>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **order** the table by clicks, in **descending** order and then **limit** the select to the top 4.

```
SELECT id, username, clicks FROM table ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 4
```

You can save the data into an array in 1 step using:

```
$users = $result->fetchAll();
```

Which can return an associative (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) or numeric (PDO::FETCH_NUM) array (amongst other options).